# Quickly changes the app version

Tags: application-development, quickly

When I share an app with the command:

```
quickly share
```

The app version is changed in the glade file, in the setup.py file... and upload to the PPA (Then the build will not admit a below version).

Can I disable this? Can I restore the PPA for a right version as 0.0.3? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can change the version number of your apps by using `dch -v`. What is the present version number? And, tell me the version number that you want to use newly.

Comment: Thanks @vine_user :) quickly overwrites the app version to YYM, where YY is the year and M the mont.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quickly will still overwrite the version number, so if you want to use a different versioning scheme than the default `month.release` one, you can override it for each release using the `<version>` parameter.

```
quickly release <version>
```

Note that you'll need to run the command with the parameter for each release you make, as Quickly won't remember your versioning scheme and will fall back to the default if you don't specify the `<version>` parameter.

The support for the `<version>` parameter in the packaging-related commands is as follows:

- **package** - doesn't change the version number, so no need for the  parameter
- **share** - does not support the `<version>` parameter, it appends `-public` to the version, but it does not bump it.
- **release** - fully supports the `<version>` parameter
- **submitubuntu** - fully supports the `<version>` parameter

In any case, a really easy thing to do is to just delete the package with your old versioning scheme from the PPA and re-run `quickly share`

Answer (score 3):

You can change the version number using this command at the top directory of project.

```
dch -v 0.0.3-xxx
```

Supposing an error comes out, use `-b` option:

```
dch -b
```

Then, edit debian/chagelog compulsorily and eliminate the portion of 12.07-xxxx.

Your package version number on launchpad is higher than the new package number, so you have to use another package name, or use higher version number than  present package, or delete present package.

**How to delete present packages on PPA.**

- open your PPA page.
- click "View package details"  link that is right middle of site.
- click "Delete packages"  link that is right top of site.
- select package.
- describe "Deletion comment" (Optional), if you want.
- click "Request Deletion" button.

**Cautions:** The easiest alternative to replace a broken source is always to upload a package with a higher version number and let the system automatically supersede and remove the older version. You should not rely on deletion requests to re-upload the same source version with different contents.

More information is there, 
https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Deleting

After deleting the old packages and 1 hour or more passes , try uploading new package.